# PHP SoapClient error with line endings

Tags: php, linux, windows, soap, line-endings

I have a SoapServer running on a windows machine.

When I try to instantiate a SoapClient object from a linux machine, it fails with a nice

```
PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://172.23.5.124:8181/Pyxvital.exe/wsdl/IPyxvital' : Premature end of data in tag definitions line 1
```

If I try on a windows machine, it works.

I'm not sure, but it seems to come from the fact that the Soap server sends windows line endings in the XML response (I can see ^M in the XML when I open the WSDL file).

I changed the encoding in the SoapClient options, but I can't find if I can do anything to the line endings (I tryed auto_detect_line_endings in php.ini, but it seems to affect only fgets).

Thanks.

Comment: Try opening in WSDL file in a program such as dreamweaver which allows you to change the EOL type. When opened, change the EOL type to Linux and save the file.

Comment: Saving the WSDL and using this one was the thing. Thanks. I thought I would still have problems then when sending requests and getting responses.

Comment: No problems glad it was solved.